# C Macros: Select macro using concatenation of string and number

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, c-strings

I have huge amount of macros (not mine) tailed with numbers:

```
#define MACRO_1 do_something1();
#define MACRO_2 do_something2();
#define MACRO_3 do_something3();
.
.
```

With these auxiliary macros:

```
#define TO_STRING(x) #x
#define SELECT_MACRO(id) "MACRO_"TO_STRING(id)
```

I want to be able to select the desired macro, for example I'm doing it with: `SELECT_MACRO(3)`, the problem is that it's translated to `"MACRO_""3"`
and I have a problem to use some APIs in our code due to the double quotes inside this string.

Is there a way to make it without the quotes?

Comment: Is id a variable from run time? Or an integer constant like `1` or `42`?

Comment: This is an integer constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [token concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) operator `##`:

```
#define SELECT_MACRO(id) MACRO_##id
```

With this `SELECT_MACRO(1)` expands to `MACRO_1`.

---

Btw:

> it's translated to `"MACRO_""3"` and I have a problem [...] due to the double quotes inside this string.

There are no double quotes inside the string. It's a single string `"MACRO_3"`. Adjacent string literals (here `"MACRO_"` and `"3"`) are concatenated (after preprocessing).

Comment: In fact l looked into the c-preprocessor output and that's what I saw. anyway, your solution helped, thanks!

Comment: @elady Adjacent string literals are concatenated _after_ the preprocessing phase so the preprocessing output would just show adjacent string literals. A double quote _inside_ a string literal would be shown as `\"`.

Comment: Well so it's a bit difficult to me to explain why it didn't work before.